# Laravel 5.8 - one route two different controller action

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, action

In laravel 5.8, I have have 2 type of url.

/news/{category} - > send to news controller index action, if have category bind 
/news/{news} - > send to news controller details action, if have news bind 
Another case abort with 404.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel and almost all frameworks and routing systems I'm aware of, the Route and Controller/Action relationship is 1:1. Each route can only have one controller or action to handle it.

If I understand your question correctly, you have a single route pattern of `/news/{parameter}`, and you want one of three things to happen:

1. `{parameter}` contains a valid Category slug. Retrieve the category and display the appropriate view.
2. `{parameter}` contains a valid Article (details) slug. Retrieve the article and display the appropriate view.
3. `{parameter}` does not contain a valid category or article slug, and thus is not found. Return a 404 error.

You'll still need only a single controller action, but you can separate the logic to make it easy to understand:

*routes/web.php:*

```php
Route::get('/news/{param}', 'NewsController@index');
```

*app/Http/Controllers/NewsController (with pseudo code):*

```php
class NewsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(string $param)
    {
        if ($category = Category::whereSlug($param)->first()) {
            // Return your category view.
        }

        if ($article = Article::whereSlug($param)->first()) {
            // Return your article view.
        }

        \abort(404);
    }
}
```

I would personally recommend against sharing a common URL structure for two different entity types like this. It opens the possibility for name conflicts (a Category and Article have the same slug) and can make the user experience confusing. (It might hurt search engine optimizations or results, also, but that's just speculation - I don't have anything to confirm or deny that.)